# Building an application with Schema-less database as embedded (no-server database)

Tags: .net, nosql

**The need:**
I am building a .NET application that reads large XML files and write them to a database.
The app is mainly an MVC 4 viewer for the data; sorting and searching. 
For the development part I am using MySql with a DAL abstract layer.
The data suppose to grow in 1GB per day.
I am looking for a no-server solution (like sqlite) that can handle this amount of data.
There is no need of any security (db user management) on the database file.

**Why Embeded**

1. I dont want to maintain another PORT (i know its not really a need, but I prefer that way).
2. I want to have a very lightweight installation process. (copy to IIS folder and start to work, only dlls, no server).

I am looking for something that is well known in the .NET environment and is free for commercial use. (why free? because we dont have investment yet. we might switch to a commercial license once the product profit)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Schema less, .NET and embedded?

Try Raven DB: http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/embedded

You can start with the free version and considering adding paid enterprise features as needed.

Comment: There is no question about the fact that raven db is one of the bests there is. but I contact support and I need to pay 1500$ yearly. they dont offer free license unless your product is free and open source. thanks